# App crash when receiving data size 30 MB is loaded about 50% from bluetooth

Tags: java, android, service, crash, bluetooth

i am new Android DEV and my app developing is about send data that format to byte array via bluetooth and i have use bluetooth library [here](http://simonguest.com/2013/04/19/transferring-data-via-bluetooth-on-android-android-btxfr/).it easy to use and lite weigth.
,app is running fine when size of data <= 15 MB.but App crash happen when receiving data size  about 30 MB was loaded in progress bar about 50 % . i don't know why and how to fix it.

another question, i have implement recieved data activity to  service.But when service start it allocate the memory about 20 MB that to much and alway increase allocate ram itself when reciveing data .finally app crash again

Comment: You should add some code you are using. It's hard to judge if you used it at all. All we can assume is that you are trying to read the file at once or loading it in the memory at once instead of i.e. receiving it in small chunks and writing this data to the internal memory (flash or SD card)

Comment: Post your code with the logcat of the crash !! No one can guess the code and error unless it is simple

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on memory allocated from java code. The max allocated size depends on android version and device vendor.

Comment: If it is that you say.why does it not crash on sender too?

Comment: Maybe because of buffering&

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing app for HoneyComb or above then in the manifest file of your app just add

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

under `<application>` tags attributes. It should work. But it can slow down other apps by allocating enough heap to your alone app.